# Material-UI Change Drawer Color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How to set background color of Material-UI Drawer? tried this, but doesn't work

```
const styles = {
  paper: {
    background: "blue"
  }
}
```

and passed it to the Drawer component:

```
 <Drawer
      classes={{ paper: classes.paper }}
      open={this.state.left}
      onClose={this.toggleDrawer("left", false)}
    >
```

and wrapped my component with material-ui's withStyles

```
export default withStyles(styles)(ResponsiveDrawer);
```

Here is the code in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xg9vp?fontsize=14).

Comment: What about trying `root` instead of  `paper`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the attribute `background` to `backgroundColor`. Like this:

```
const styles = {
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work unfortunately. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-xg9vp?fontsize=14 Here is the code compiled in Sandbox

Comment: @Oussama Take a look at this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-29zy0). I just forked that from the demo in the material-ui page and made the change. It works.

Comment: It works, thank you I should have changed the drawerPaper from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have is you're passing a [Object object] as className to Drawer component because you're using `styles` rather than classes. Try to pass a string className to your component.